# How to generate separate autoreply warning from postfix to senders not using DKIM?

Tags: postfix, dkim

Antispam/phish efforts with DKIM and SPF are weak if they're not widely enforced. I can't turn on strict no-DKIM rejection or emails will be lost, but there should be some penalty for domains not in compliance. Even medium sized recognizeable domains/hosting companies lack DKIM which is troubling.

How can I build a separate autoreply to any sender that does not employ DKIM (with some decay time before a second warning is sent for frequent senders).  This would be in effect for all users of the system when receiving mail.

(I could perhaps do this via my MUA to process headers in reply and generate a warning, but this would be only for personal messages I reply to manually, not for my entire domain of users.)

Comment: A gentler alternative is to either tweak the MUA to process missing DKIM headers with a prepended message to the target reply to bother warn them and to bother their admin. (Not sure how to do this, neo-mutt seems like the best candidate to do so).

Comment: Please note I am NOT rejecting non-DKIM mail -- ie, I will accept non-DKIM mail but my idea is to generate a separate warning email to user@ and abuse@ (or DMARC address) at sending domain.

Answer (score 5):

Please do not do this. Despite it would be nice if everyone signed their email with DKIM, this is not a good path to achieve it.

Most of the automatic responses would go to the users that are not maintaining the mail system and, thus, unable to do anything to the issue. As a result, they could either get irritated or ask for your help on how to configure their email (client) with DKIM. A question you would not be able to answer.

Instead:

- Contact the email system administrators. Ask them why they have not deployed DKIM yet, and tell them about the advantages of DKIM and DMARC.
- If you prefix the the subject lines with `[MISSING DKIM; POSSIBLY FORGED]` on delivery, you won't be sending extra auto-replies. However, the sender will notice the `Re: [MISSING...]` on every actual reply.

Comment: Users can put pressure on their admins ('services they pay money for'), otherwise there is no point. Waiting for an uneducated admin to notice they should put DKIM in place with no feedback of any kind, is an exercise in pointlessness.

The alternative is to penalize one's own users from receiving email from external non-compliant domains by blocking non-DKIM email entirely - forcing the remote admin to perhaps notice, if one's own domain's users are lucky.

Many abuse boxes go unanswered/unnoticed per my experience, so pressure via that avenue is ineffective.

Comment: @math This *pressure* idea works better when you have a less indirect mandate from the users that pay your *your* services.. those that expect to reliably receive mail from (and only from) the other services they pay for. Check whether your junk reporting is minimal-effort for your users and state-of-the-art on your aggregation & processing side. So far I found the "hey this is spoofing you, consider XYZ" line widely accepted as good justification to demand some attention from the administrators that left it unnecessarily difficult to reject junk.

Comment: I've added an alternative approach that is less annoying but might be as effective in causing the pressure you want.

Comment: ok sure but how to autoimpliment it then? would have to be MUA based, as it affects subject line (say, neomutt?)

Answer (score 3):

The [problem Esa Jokinen](https://serverfault.com/a/1122026/250204) rightly points out about such messages not being seen by a suitable audience does not make the general idea entirely hopeless. Because you do not need to send this as new messages. Instead, leave such request in places that will (primarily) be seen by users & mail operators that do care and are able *to do anything to the issue*. The primary being:

**SMTP extended status code & text**

– the message that administrative folk glance at when trying to determine the nature of a problem with delivering mail to you. The response **you already send** in every case of spam filtering *false positives*. If you, like many operators, are guilty of custom, yet still [unactionable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unactionable) messages, then start using that free real estate to leave a guide (or a pointer to a guide) how the situation could be mitigated. No new chatter, no change in accept/reject policy, just improving what is already communicated for some unavoidable share of incoming messages.

1. Bad: wasting of the ability to append free-form:

   `550 rejected for failing to meet criteria which I wont reveal hahaha`
2. Better: replace the existing text unconditionally with your link:

   ```
   550-5.7.1 Too similar to previously received junk, Please review
   550 5.7.1 https://support.example/mail/1337 for more information.
   ```
3. Fancy: If you are able to conditionally trigger this only on spam-rejects where nothing obvious (same domain, [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC), known party) clarifies authorization, you can even include specific calls for action depending on what is most likely helpful to the sending side:

   ```
   550-5.7.1 Your system example.com does not appear authorized to
   550-5.7.1 send as example.org - Such messages could still be accepted
   550 5.7.1 if your mail provider configures DKIM for you.
   ```

If you have more than one spam filtering software - check all respective negative answers that you send with non-negligible frequency whether they truly use a more standardized & useful text. Just take care to not mismatch messages for transient and permanent rejections.

Comment: Not accepting any non-signed mail is probably too strict, isn't it?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Still, improving SMTP status text synergizes quite well with a gradually less permissive policy. E.g. exempting signed mail from provider-level reputation database lookups, while continuing to not care about signatures for most. As long as I am not trying to tell the whole internet how to run their servers, people seem to be quite happy finding a solution to their problem already written to their logs.

Comment: I fully agree that detailed status will be more useful for everybody and won't make the system less secure (e.g. spammers won't read those status replies anyway, but for admins it will be helpful). I still think that rejecting mail on the basis "it has no signature" is way too strict, for whatever reason: it's *your* user who is not happy not receiving mail.

Comment: exactly. i will not reject mail, just generate a separate bounce/warning to abuse@/DMARC contact and the sender warning them their system does not use DKIM and may be rejected in future

Answer (score 2):

I think this should not be fully automated. Rejecting all non-signed mail is too strict, and changing subjects could be annoying too, and this time it will annoy your own users. Also consider the amount of stress for all parties when you finally apply this system, the day when *your users* suddenly won't be able to receive a lot of mail that was perfectly working yesterday, or when a lot of mail happen to have this garbage in the subject. I bet they will press *you* to revert the change, rather than trying to convince their peers to press their admins — this will be by far easiest apparent resolution for them.

You need to consider each domain on case by case basis and what can be automated is statistics. On reception you can collect the counts for each sender domain, how many mails it sent to you, and how many of them appear to be human-made and how many reverse traffic is seen (e.g. replies).

Then, you may select the domain which showed substantial traffic and build notices to their postmasters or domain owners in a semi-automated fashion, or, perhaps, apply the processing that is suggested in other answers only to those domains, or convince only a few users who talk with those domains a lot to add notifications in their MUAs. This will make the whole inception of the system less stressful, notices will be addressed more directly, while you won't bother notifying the operators of systems from which you had only seen only a stray messages without any response in their direction.

---

**Update.** Technically you can use something like [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/1119007/postfix-bounce-incoming-email-but-still-deliver/1119040#1119040) to create your notification emails. But again, I strongly advise you against sending such notifications to end users. They don't bother whether mails are DKIM signed or not. Email RFCs define `postmaster@<domain>` address for such notices.

If a part of email traffic from a domain is signed, and part is not, I think it is not worth writing to a postmaster at all. They prove they know what DKIM is because they are using it; the fact they don't use it for some mail could only mean they know what they are doing and there are reasons for doing so. If there is a DMARC policy, you should comply with it, because it is the manifestation of their view on the problem, and your notices and explanations won't do any good at all.

Comment: my suggestion does not block mail and thus my users will not miss any. however there will be an extra email in my original suggestion replying to abuse@ (or any DMARC address, but if they had DMARC they'd have DKIM) and the user warning them they're not using DKIM and email risks being rejected by this and other systems.

Comment: I agree with @EsaJokinen, it wouldn't be effective. This will, again, turn user's anger against you, rather than against those admins. Because for users it is not important whether mails are DKIM signed or not, but they will be annoyed by your mails, which you added artificially and without apparent reason, and which are absolutely unsolicited. You need to *only* send mails to "abuse@" (the standard defined a `postmaster@` for that purpose, by the way).

Comment: clearly in the long history of the internet, with systems that are still functional (and not professional or erstwhile spammers) but sitting at the low end of the stratum for compliance and good-behaviour, email to postmaster@ and abuse@ have been ineffective. not sure why they'd be more effective suddenly without getting their stakeholders (their users, not mine) involved.

Comment: You are going to generate a backscatter. Imagine the mail coming to you *is* a spam. And, based on this garbage which isn't worth a dime you create a new wave of mail targeting innocent people. Yes, maybe their domain is unprotected, but now it's *you* who is creating a wave of strange and unsolicited mail to them. In their point of view, *you* are an evil spammer, who sent them a crappy mail full of engineering jargon in an obvious attempt to put virus into their computer. They quickly learn their spam detectors to detect your mail as spam. Honestly, it's a proper thing to do with such crap.